# UINavigationBar left margin

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

On the iPhone 6+ it looks like UINavigationBars have a left margin of 20pt when you add custom left bar button items. On other devices it's 16pt.

That's fine, and on wider screen devices probably helps getting that button within reach of a thumb :)

I'm trying to align my UI below that (it's a table view of menu items) and it's proving tricky.

Is there any way of getting that margin programatically so I can use that value elsewhere in my UI.

Something like this would be ideal:

```
CGFloat padding = self.navigationBar.leftMargin;
```

but obviously that doesn't exist :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: May be you can use generate ratio with the use of basic screen width=320 to the bigger screen size and calculate the margin?

Comment: @iphonic That's not a good idea in the long run. Also you have to consider ipads, etc.

Comment: @LeoNatan Yes I copy that too, but I feel in any case, you need to end up doing this kind of trick.

Comment: @iphonic Not necessarily. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS 8 introduces the concept of layout margins. Each view (`UIView` and its subclasses) contains a [`layoutMargins`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layoutMargins) property, which will give you exactly what you want.

In addition, you can use [`layoutMarginsDidChange`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutMarginsDidChange) to listen to changes to the margin to react on margin changes. This method is called after initial layout as well, so you can react here and layout your view appropriately to the system provided margins. This is preferred, because depending on the device, margins may change when size class changes (iPhone 6 Plus rotation, as an example). This way, your view will always appear using the correct margins.

Read [here](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/10/02/ios8-day-by-day-day-32-layout-margins) for more information on layout margins.

Comment: Nice idea but the layout margins for both iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ on both the navigationController's view and the navigationController.navigatonBar are `8` :(

Comment: Don't use the navigation bar's layout margins. Instead, listen to the margins of your own view.

Comment: Each cell of your table view will have a left margin of either 20 or 16 depending on device type.

Answer (score 4):

**The Simple Way**

```
let leftMargin = self.navigationController?.systemMinimumLayoutMargins.leading
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the subviews of the `UINavigationBar`.

Then after you can iterate a loop to find your custom view. Using that view you can find the position of that. Like,

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[Your Custom View Class]];

    for(id object in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews){
        if([object isKindOfClass:[Your Custom View Class]]){
            UIView *item = (UIView *)object;
            NSLog(@"%f",item.frame.origin.x);
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you..